# how to add object references to mongoid document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am writing an application for my football club, and as part of this I decided to try out MongoDB in a Grape API non-rails.

So I have the following classes

Team & Coach

I am trying to define the relationship between both but cannot get this to work.

```
class Team 
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_one :coach 
end
```

initially the coach filed will be null and therefor when I add a team the only filed I pass in is *name* this I then see represented in MongoDB like so

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("59090e04cf2bee0c0a16a22f"), 
   "name" : "team A"
}
```

then when I come to add the coach I get a 201 returned from the API no errors but the coach is missing from MongoDB please someone tell me what I am doing wrong it's driving me insane

Comment: Please add the code that shows how you are trying to create these objects.

Comment: creation is not the problem, every time I try to add *belongs_to* or *has_many* the relationships break down